# group data from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a DB like this:

```
id | start               | stop                | reason
1  | 2017-10-09 08:00:00 | 2017-10-09 08:15:00 | fault 1
2  | 2017-10-09 08:15:00 | 2017-10-09 08:30:00 | fault 2
3  | 2017-10-09 08:30:00 | 2017-10-09 09:00:00 | fault 3
4  | 2017-10-09 10:00:00 | 2017-10-09 11:15:00 | fault 1
5  | 2017-10-09 14:00:00 | 2017-10-09 15:00:00 | fault 2
```

I would like to make a pie chart of this data using flot charts but I need to group the data first and only display the total duration as a percentage, resulting in an array like:

```
0   
label:  "Fault 1"
data:   46.15385
1   
label:  "Fault 2"
data:   38.46154
2   
label:  "Fault 3"
data:   15.38462
```

I am having trouble grouping them, I thought I could use in_array but I am having trouble with this, here is my code so far:-

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . STATE_TABLE . " INNER JOIN " . DOWNTIME_TABLE . 
    " ON " . STATE_TABLE . ".reason = " . DOWNTIME_TABLE . ".faultId
    WHERE ('$shiftEnd' > start AND stop > '$shiftStart')
    OR ('$shiftEnd' > start AND stop is null) ORDER BY start DESC";
if ( !($result = $db->sql_query($sql)) )
{
    die('Could not query STATUS_TABLE database');
}
$totalDowntime = 0;
while( $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result) ) {
    $start = $row['start'];
    $stop = $row['stop'] == null ? $currentTime : $row['stop'];
    $faultStart = $shiftStart > $start ? $shiftStart : $start;
    $faultStop = $stop > $shiftEnd ? $shiftEnd : $stop;

    $duration = get_time_difference($faultStart, $faultStop, 'seconds');

    $totalDowntime += $duration;
    $faults[] = $row;
}
$db->sql_freeresult($result);

$output = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($faults as $fault) {

    $start = $fault['start'];
    $stop = $fault['stop'] == null ? $currentTime : $fault['stop'];
    $description = $fault['description'];   
    $faultStart = $shiftStart > $start ? $shiftStart : $start;
    $faultStop = $stop > $shiftEnd ? $shiftEnd : $stop;

    $duration = get_time_difference($faultStart, $faultStop, 'seconds');

    $percent = ($duration / $totalDowntime) * 100;

    if (in_array($description, $output)) {
        $output[]['data'] += $percent;
    } else {
        $output[$i]['label'] = $description;
        $output[$i]['data'] = $percent;
    }
    $i++;
}

die(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: What is your error?  What's wrong with the grouping?

Comment: [Perform the date maths](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) as part of your SQL query, and total them together by reason.

Comment: Sari Rahal I don't get an error but the data doesn't group and spits out 5 lines instead of 3.

Comment: Scuzzy I didn't know I could perform the date maths as part of my query I will look into that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you group your data using your SQL query, so that you get the array ready for plotting right from MySQL?

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/152bcc/4/0

For a table like this:

```
create table faults (id int not null, start timestamp not null, stop timestamp, reason text not null);
insert into faults (id, start, stop, reason) values 
(1, '2017-10-09 08:00:00', '2017-10-09 08:15:00', 'fault 1'),
(2, '2017-10-09 08:15:00', '2017-10-09 08:30:00', 'fault 2'),
(3, '2017-10-09 08:30:00', '2017-10-09 09:00:00', 'fault 3'),
(4, '2017-10-09 10:00:00', '2017-10-09 11:15:00', 'fault 1'),
(5, '2017-10-09 14:00:00', '2017-10-09 15:00:00', 'fault 2'),
(6, '2017-10-09 14:00:00',  NULL                , 'fault 2');
```

You can use the `TIMEDIFF()` function and group by the "reason" column. The `COALESCE()` function returns the first `NOT NULL` value from a list, so it can be used to replace the current timestamp when `stop` is null:

```
select 
  reason as label,
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(stop, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), start)))) as data,
  SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(stop, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), start))) as data_seconds
from faults
group by reason 
order by reason;

|   label |     data | data_seconds |
|---------|----------|--------------|
| fault 1 | 01:30:00 |         5400 |
| fault 2 | 13:23:02 |        48182 |
| fault 3 | 00:30:00 |         1800 |
```

Comment: That certainly is a lot cleaner than my code however it is not adding the faults together only showing the first ones, from my example I would expect: | label | data_interval | data_seconds | |---------|---------------|--------------| | fault 1 | 01:30:00 | 5400 | | fault 2 | 01:15:00 | 4500 | | fault 3 | 00:30:00 | 1800 |

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of above response, not sure I can do any better in the comments section

Comment: @Chris Oops, sorry! I completely forgot about summing up the time differences in seconds. I've edited the answer and I'm working on the seconds to interval conversion.

Comment: Thats great thanks, I guess sql is a lot more powerful than I thought. Guess I need to learn it as it it would probably clean up a lot more of my other functions

Comment: I thought this was a good solution but stop can sometimes be null in this event I have to use the current time to complete the calculation, or the stop time may exceed the end of the current shift but i need to have the total for that shift, could this be worked into the query or do I have to revert back to doing it in php?

Comment: @Chris: To replace `stop` with the current timestamp you can use `COALESCE()`, I've updated the answer. Sorry, but I didn't understand the "end of shift" requirement, could you explain it a little more? Maybe update your question with a table with sample data that represents all your use cases...